# Concurrent filing of I-130 and I-485

Tags: visa, immigration, usa

I am filing forms I-130 and I-485 for my wife. I have a couple of questions regarding this. Can I file forms I-765 and I-131 with the application (she is in the US on H1B)? And if I can file I-765, what should be the "Eligibility Category" in question 20?

Comment: you are a US citizen, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can file forms [I-765 and I-131 concurrently with the I-485 Adjustment of Status](https://www.uscis.gov/forms/filing-directions-obtain-employment-authorization-and-advance-parole-card-where-adjustment-status-application-pending). Since you are filing the I-765 with a "normal" Adjustment of Status your Eligibility Category will be (c)(9) ([see 7A in the instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-765instr.pdf?download=1)).

Comment: and I will add that it's free to file I-765 for EAD and I-131 for Advance Parole for I-485 applicants